# SQL Distinct Group by

Tags: sql, select, group-by

SQL : Group by country & Count, very simple but I’m lost
I have on my Table1

```
Country    | Optin    | 
--------------------------
USA        | 1        |
USA        | 1        |      
GERMANY    | 0        |      
USA        | 1        |          
GERMANY    | 1        |         
JAPON      | 1        |
```

I want to return this table, I just want count by country when optin part=1

```
Country    | Optin    | 
--------------------------
USA        | 3        |
GERMANY    | 1        |
JAPON      | 1        |  


SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Optin = 1
GROUP BY Country
```

Answer (score 1):

> I just want count by country when optin part=1

Use `COUNT`(or `SUM` since all `optin`'s returned = 1) with `GROUP BY country`:

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(optin) 
FROM table1
WHERE optin = 1
GROUP BY country;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9658d/3)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  Country, SUM(CASE WHEN Optin = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalOptin
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY Country
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecbc1/1)